# MongoDB aggregation : Keep value from previous document if null or not exists

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that contains time-based metrics. I only store them if they change over time and I want to keep their previous value in the aggregation result.

Here's an extract of the collection :

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("6115150f01d7d0426bcd0390"),
  "conf": "conference123",
  "uid": "2dd8b4e3-9dcd-4da6-bc36-aa0988dc9642",
  "log": [
    {
      "dt": ISODate("2021-08-12T12:33:49.782Z"),
      "connection_quality": 60,
      "video_bitrate": 150
    },
    {
      "dt": ISODate("2021-08-12T12:34:19.781Z"),
      "video_bitrate": 145
      // connection_quality didn't change so it's not stored
    },
    {
      "dt": ISODate("2021-08-12T12:34:30.781Z"),
      "video_bitrate": 130
      // connection_quality didn't change so it's not stored
    },
    {
      "dt": ISODate("2021-08-12T12:34:49.787Z"),
      "connection_quality": 100,
      "video_bitrate": 150
    },
    {
      "dt": ISODate("2021-08-12T12:35:19.789Z"),
      "video_bitrate": 160
      // connection_quality didn't change so it's not stored
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried the following aggregation but I don't know what to put after the last stage :

```
[{
    $match: {
        conf: 'conference123',
        uid: '2dd8b4e3-9dcd-4da6-bc36-aa0988dc9642'
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: '$log'
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        "Date": '$log.dt',
        'User ID': '$uid',
        'Connection Quality': "$log.cq"
    }
}]
```

Here's the result that I get

```
[
  {
    "Date": ISODate("2021-08-12T12:33:49.782Z"),
    "User ID":"2dd8b4e3-9dcd-4da6-bc36-aa0988dc9642",
    "Connection Quality":60
  },
  {
    "Date": ISODate("2021-08-12T12:34:19.781Z"),
    "User ID":"2dd8b4e3-9dcd-4da6-bc36-aa0988dc9642"
  },
  {
    "Date": ISODate("2021-08-12T12:34:30.781Z"),
    "User ID":"2dd8b4e3-9dcd-4da6-bc36-aa0988dc9642"
  },
  {
    "Date": ISODate("2021-08-12T12:34:49.787Z"),
    "User ID":"2dd8b4e3-9dcd-4da6-bc36-aa0988dc9642",
    "Connection Quality":100
  },
  {
    "Date": ISODate("2021-08-12T12:35:19.789Z"),
    "User ID":"2dd8b4e3-9dcd-4da6-bc36-aa0988dc9642"
  }
]
```

But this is what I want to display

```
[
  {
    "Date": ISODate("2021-08-12T12:33:49.782Z"),
    "User ID":"2dd8b4e3-9dcd-4da6-bc36-aa0988dc9642",
    "Connection Quality":60
  },
  {
    "Date": ISODate("2021-08-12T12:34:19.781Z"),
    "User ID":"2dd8b4e3-9dcd-4da6-bc36-aa0988dc9642",
    "Connection Quality":60
  },
  {
    "Date": ISODate("2021-08-12T12:34:30.781Z"),
    "User ID":"2dd8b4e3-9dcd-4da6-bc36-aa0988dc9642",
    "Connection Quality":60
  },
  {
    "Date": ISODate("2021-08-12T12:34:49.787Z"),
    "User ID":"2dd8b4e3-9dcd-4da6-bc36-aa0988dc9642",
    "Connection Quality":100
  },
  {
    "Date": ISODate("2021-08-12T12:35:19.789Z"),
    "User ID":"2dd8b4e3-9dcd-4da6-bc36-aa0988dc9642",
    "Connection Quality":100
  }
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straight way to do this operation,

- `$map` to iterate loop of log array, check condition if `connection_quality` type is missing then go to select previous `connection_quality` otherwise return the current object
- `$filter` to iterate loop of log and by conditions are: `dt` should less than  and `connection_quality` should not missing
- now we have to select the latest `connection_quality` from above filtered result so using `$last` we will select last object
- `$let` to declare a variable and do above filter operation and return just `connection_quality` value
- `$unwind` to deconstruct the `log` array
- `$project` to project the result as per your requirement

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      conf: "conference123",
      uid: "2dd8b4e3-9dcd-4da6-bc36-aa0988dc9642"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      log: {
        $map: {
          input: "$log",
          as: "l",
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $eq: [{ $type: "$$l.connection_quality" }, "missing"] },
              {
                dt: "$$l.dt",
                connection_quality: {
                  $let: {
                    vars: {
                      log: {
                        $last: {
                          $filter: {
                            input: "$log",
                            cond: {
                              $and: [
                                { $lt: ["$$this.dt", "$$l.dt"] },
                                {
                                  $ne: [{ $type: "$$this.connection_quality" }, "missing"]
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    in: "$$log.connection_quality"
                  }
                }
              },
              "$$l"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$log" },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "Date": "$log.dt",
      "User ID": "$uid",
      "Connection Quality": "$log.connection_quality"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0SujRSzq31_)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with reduce
The bellow query adds the `connection_quality` if `null` or `missing` with the
value of the previous member that had `connection_quality`

It starts with a default 60, for example if the first member didn't had also

```json
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "log": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": "$log",
              "initialValue": [
                60,
                []
              ],
              "in": {
                "$let": {
                  "vars": {
                    "prv_value_logs": "$$value",
                    "log": "$$this"
                  },
                  "in": {
                    "$let": {
                      "vars": {
                        "prv_value": {
                          "$arrayElemAt": [
                            "$$prv_value_logs",
                            0
                          ]
                        },
                        "logs": {
                          "$arrayElemAt": [
                            "$$prv_value_logs",
                            1
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      "in": {
                        "$cond": [
                          {
                            "$and": [
                              {
                                "$ne": [
                                  "$$log.connection_quality",
                                  null
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "$ne": [
                                  {
                                    "$type": "$$log.connection_quality"
                                  },
                                  "missing"
                                ]
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          [
                            "$$log.connection_quality",
                            {
                              "$concatArrays": [
                                "$$logs",
                                [
                                  "$$log"
                                ]
                              ]
                            }
                          ],
                          [
                            "$$prv_value",
                            {
                              "$concatArrays": [
                                "$$logs",
                                [
                                  {
                                    "$mergeObjects": [
                                      "$$log",
                                      {
                                        "connection_quality": "$$prv_value"
                                      }
                                    ]
                                  }
                                ]
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wXJrKBsNA8b)

It doesn't change the document, just adds the missing `connection_quality`, if you want to change it after, you can add more stages.

Solution is fast for arrays <500 members.

---

**Edit1**

The slow part is not the `$reduce` its the `$concat` because MongodDB
doesn't have a way to add 1 element to the end fast.
Its not how many arrays you have, but how big they are.

I was curious why you said you cant use reduce and map/filter worked for you(because looks like O(n^2)), so i did a benchmark.

```json
1000 elements (the log)
"Elapsed time: 44.408292 msecs"   //reduce 
"Elapsed time: 167.653179 msecs"  //map and filter 3x

5000 elements
"Elapsed time: 263.549371 msecs"   
"Elapsed time: 3298.880892 msecs"  //10x+

10000 elements
"Elapsed time: 996.340296 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 14765.732331 msecs" //10x+
```

This is only for 1 document collection, so both solutions are very slow, not usable for big collections with big arrays > 500 elements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but there will be performances issues with $reduce because I have a large number of arrays

Comment: you tried it and it was slow? and then you tried map+filter solution described above and it was faster?i did benchmark see edit, if it works for you its fine, i was just curious.